# How do I embed a csv file into a Word Document with Python docx

Tags: python-2.7, csv, insert, python-docx

I'm opening a docx file and I want to embed into it a csv file.

The csv should be displayed as an icon.

How would I set it's ecaxt position in my Word File?

My code so far is:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import csv
from docx import Document
import datetime


today = datetime.date.today()

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
#filename = askopenfilename(title='Specify data csv file',filetypes=[('text files', '.csv')]) # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
filename='C:/Documents and Settings/K/My Documents/LiClipse Workspace/WO_templates/WO_templates/data.csv'

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    data_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in data_csv:
        if row[3]<>'Name':
            document = Document('2G_Template.docx')

            for table in document.tables:
                for _cell in table._cells:
                    for paragraph in _cell.paragraphs:
                        if '%DATE%' in paragraph.text:
                            paragraph.text=str(today.day)+'/'+str(today.month)+'/'+str(today.year)
                        if 'R%RR%' in paragraph.text:
                            paragraph.text='R'+row[0]                       
                        if '%DESC%' in paragraph.text:
                            paragraph.text=row[1]

            for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                if '%DEL_PLAN%' in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text='Deletion PLan: '+row[2]



            document.save(row[3]+'.docx')
```

The next step in each cycle should be to select a csv file and embed it in the word file. It would be the equivalent of a paste special action in Word, with the option Display as Icon selected.

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29628625/edit) to include [the code you have written so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to embed the csv using pywin32 library.

```
import win32com.client as win32
.
.
.
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc=word.Documents.Open(doc_path)
word.Visible = False
.
.
.
doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(FileName=doc_path3,DisplayAsIcon=1,Range=range1,IconLabel="CSV",IconFileName=doc_path4)

word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(doc_path2)
doc.Close()
```